# NoClassDefFound jogl

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, jogl

I came across this error that my compiler gives me:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/media/opengl/GLProfile`

I do have `jogl-all.jar` and `gluegen-rt.jar` in my classpath, and I have no idea why this error still occurs. Any help?

**EDIT:**

I just came over this:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/164527-java-error-when-opening-fig-files

MATLAB also affected by this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13519209/why-wont-this-java-opengl-jogl-program-run

Comment: @GK27 Did you see that I already have those in my classpath?

Comment: Yep  i have seen it ,I guess there  should be  some minor difference while adding the jars .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numerous packages have been moved in JOGL 2.3.1, we no longer use "javax.media" and "javax.nativewindow":
[https://jogamp.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=682](http://jogamp.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=682)

Just use the right package names and it should work.

Edit.: You have to use a version of Matlab compatible with JOGL 2.3.1 (recommended if possible) or to switch back to an older version of JOGL (not recommended).