# World Wind Java SDK 2.0 Netbeans 8 MCVE Project

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8, jogl, worldwind

After spending time on research and following the tutorials / recommendations, I’m still not able to start my project using **NASA World Wind SDK 2** in **Netbeans 8** on a **32-bit Windows 7** machine.

Due to the World Wind SDK 2.0 Update to JOGL 2.3x, most of the tutorials are deprecated and not useful any more.

What have I tried so far:

- Tried the **old approach** (http://wiki.netbeans.org/HelloWorldWindJavaSDK) => does not work anymore (I adopted the approach to the new Jogl-all.jar).
- Read the **How to setup WWJ** thread in the official WW Forum (http://forum.worldwindcentral.com/showthread.php?20383-How-to-setup-WWJ) without any useful help.
- Had a look in the Wiki on **WWJava in NetBeans IDE** http://www.worldwindcentral.com/wiki/WWJava_in_NetBeans_IDE => deprecated.
- Had a read in the **README.txt** due to the note (https://goworldwind.org/releases/) => Following these instructions without success

  > Note on using the JOGL libraries without the default runtime extraction of native binaries.
  >   This is accomplished by modifying World Wind's JOGL distribution to load native binaries directly from the library
  >   path instead of dynamically using the native binary JAR files. Here are instructions on how to implement this:

  - 1) Extract the GlueGen and JOGL native binary JAR files for the desired platform.
    These JAR files follow the naming pattern gluegen-rt-natives-PLATFORM.jar and jogl-all-natives-PLATFORM.jar
  - 2) Place the extracted native binaries either in the program's working directory or in a location specified as the
    library path.
    The following JOGL user's guide page outlines supported library path variables:
    https://jogamp.org/jogl/doc/userguide/index.html#traditionallibraryloading
  - 3) Remove the GlueGen and JOGL native binary JAR files from your application's workspace.
    JOGL attempts to use the native binary JAR files before loading from the library path, so these files must not be
    deployed with the application.
  - 4) When running, specify the JVM argument -Djogamp.gluegen.UseTempJarCache=false
- Downloaded the World Wind Java SDK 2 and started the example => it’s working! So I tried to use the **run-demo.bat** in my project and changing pathes etc.  => it’s **not** working cause

  ```
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.media.opengl.awt.GLJPanel
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
  ... 37 more
  ```
- Searched for `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.media.opengl.awt.GLJPanel` finding several tutorial like ([Why won't this Java OpenGL (JOGL) program run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13519209/why-wont-this-java-opengl-jogl-program-run)) with the following solution => Even with the classpath set correctly (as I expect) I still get the error

  > As you have already compiled the file with JOGL jar files, you just need to make sure that you have these files in your classpath at runtime:

  ```
  java -cp gluegen-rt.jar;jogl-all.jar;. SimpleScene
  ```

**Summary:**

Does anybody know whether there is a sample example project (well configured) for NASA World Wind Java 2 SDK? The Github repository (https://github.com/NASAWorldWind/WorldWindJava) does not provide projects being valid for a reuse.

**My goal** is to have (and later of course provide for the community) a **Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**.

Likely it’s quite easy to fix my problem but after spending some time I’m probably caught in a **failure state**...

Comment: Replace "javax.media" by "com.jogamp" to make it work with the latest version.

Comment: @gouessej The good news is that I found my fault and I'm able to built and **run** my project! I will definitively build a sample project for others - unfortunately I don't know how quickly... I will keep you informed.