# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when using IfcJava3DViewer of APSTEX IFC Framework

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, ifc

I'm using APSTEX IFC Framework to creat a IFC 3D Viewer in my Java program.
My code is as follow.

```
import com.apstex.ifcjava3dviewer.IfcJava3DViewer;

public class JavaViewer2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IfcJava3DViewer ifcViewer = new IfcJava3DViewer();
    }
}
```

The error is as followed:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jogamp/opengl/GLCapabilitiesImmutable
    at com.apstex.javax.media.j3d.Pipeline$PipelineCreator.run(SourceFile:74)
    at com.apstex.javax.media.j3d.Pipeline$PipelineCreator.run(SourceFile:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.apstex.javax.media.j3d.Pipeline.b(SourceFile:91)
    at com.apstex.javax.media.j3d.MasterControl.c(SourceFile:858)
    at com.apstex.javax.media.j3d.VirtualUniverse.<clinit>(SourceFile:267)
    at com.apstex.gui.core.controller.ApplicationController.<init>(SourceFile:1097)
    at com.apstex.gui.core.kernel.Kernel.getApplicationController(SourceFile:59)
    at com.apstex.ifcjava3dviewer.IfcJava3DPanel.<init>(SourceFile:71)
    at com.apstex.ifcjava3dviewer.IfcJava3DViewer.<init>(SourceFile:38)
    at test.main.JavaViewer2.main(JavaViewer2.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jogamp.opengl.GLCapabilitiesImmutable
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 11 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.apstex.javax.media.j3d.VirtualUniverse
    at com.apstex.javax.media.j3d.Canvas3D.<clinit>(SourceFile:3821)
    at com.apstex.gui.ifc.views.view3d.j3d.ModelViewer.<init>(SourceFile:93)
    at com.apstex.gui.ifc.views.view3d.j3d.ModelViewer.<init>(SourceFile:79)
    at com.apstex.ifcjava3dviewer.IfcJava3DPanel.<init>(SourceFile:1079)
    at com.apstex.ifcjava3dviewer.IfcJava3DViewer.<init>(SourceFile:38)
    at test.main.JavaViewer2.main(JavaViewer2.java:7)
```

How can I correct the error?

Comment: This is a CLASSPATH (or module-path) problem. Class `com.jogamp.opengl.GLCapabilitiesImmutable` is not found. [edit] your question and add the command you enter to launch your java program.

Comment: Have you seen this question: [Why won't this Java OpenGL (JOGL) program run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13519209/why-wont-this-java-opengl-jogl-program-run)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the two commends above to help me solve the problem. By installing a library of JOGL the program works.